# Trying to read in some command line arguments for a console application

Tags: .net, command-line, console-application

i've got a pretty simple .NET console application. I wish to pass in some command line arguments ... nothing tough there.

Now, the kicker is, i usually have a LIST of items i wish to pass in, for one argument. In this case, a list of files. I'm not sure of the best way to do this.

```
eg. myapp.exe files=aaa.txt,bbb.txt,ccc.txt
```

but what about file names with spaces? Should i comma delimate it?

to make things interesting, i've got other args, which accept single values .. so i'm not sure if i should put all the arg data in double quotes..

```
eg. myapp.exe files=aaa.txt,bbb.txt formatting=true foo=hello
```

or

```
eg myapp.exe files="aaa.txt","bbb.txt" formatting="true" foo="hello"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a bit late for the program you are working on, but here's how you could do it using [Mono.Options](http://www.ndesk.org/Options)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //let's try this mono.options thing shall we?
    string xapfile = null;
    var files = new List<string>();
    var p = new Mono.Options.OptionSet()
    {
        { "xap=", v => xapfile =v },
        { "file:", v => files.Add(v)}
    };
    List<string> extra = p.Parse(args);


    Console.WriteLine(@"
    xap = '{0}', 
    file(s)= {1}", 
         xapfile, 
         string.Join(",", files.ToArray())
    );
    Console.WriteLine(@"
    left overs: {0}", 
        string.Join(Environment.NewLine, extra.ToArray())
    );
    // rest of your Main here
```

Calling syntax would be

`myapp.exe --file="file 1" --file="file 2" --file="file 3"`

You could even forgo the whole files variable and just treat the left overs as the files, and call it like `myapp.exe "file 1" "file 2" "file 3"` and pluck the files out of the extra list.

Mono.Options is pretty powerful. You don't even have to use --, it appears you can use `/file=` or `-file=`

Unfortunately, Windows doesn't do globbing for you (unless you're passing the options to a powershell cmdlet), so you have to do it yourself. It's pretty easy though, [here's](http://brianary.blogspot.com/2007/09/globbing-using-filename-wildcard.html) a bit of code I've used in the past to expand `*.foo` or `"c:\temp\*.bar|c:\temp\*.txt"`

Also, unless you wrap the filenames in talkies, I probably wouldn't comma separate the list, as comma is valid in a filename. You know that one is going to bite you one day :-) Pipe makes a good choice, but only if you wrap the whole expression in talkies, otherwise windows thinks you're doing piping. Ah, the joys of command line processing :-)

Answer (score 0):

Each argument, if it contains any spaces must be enclosed in quotes.  Otherwise I would leave quotes out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your shell probably supports [wild card globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) it is best to allow the input files to be a plain space separated list and to assume that if a file name contains spaces that it will have been escaped already either by surrounding with quotes or via \ characters.
By plain I mean contain no --f or /f style switches.

A slightly less common technique, but nor supported by all libraries doing command line parsing, is to allow multiple entries of the form `-f foo.txt -f bar.txt`. This does not play well with command line globbing (unlike the above solution).